# Css card float left and right not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a card with css, but I want the name of the company on the left and the percentage sale big on the right. I also have a div which can collapse and expand. So when I click on the div it should expand, but when I click it's totally going wrong. I really don't know how to figure this out.

I'm using float left and right:

```
.card h4 {
   float: left;
}
.card p {
   float: left;
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xvefmz1h/) example

Comment: You should try to be clearer when describing your issue. It's not clear what you mean. Please explain **why** _it's totally going wrong_.

Comment: I think for quick solution you can use <br /> <br /> after end of <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what's wrong, exactly? Is it just because the DIV description text is running into the H4 and P?

If so, tossing a "clear:both;" onto the DIV description should set it on its own line.

If you're looking to have them as three columns, you should move the DIV to be in between the H4 and P. Then, set some % widths and proper display (don't put "display:block;" on the DIV, but "display:inline-block;").

```
div.container div { 
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 1.33em;
  display:inline-block;
} 

.card h4 {
  float:left;
  width: 20%;
}

.card p {
  float:right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

If that's not the problem, perhaps more detail into what's wrong and what's desired would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, all you had to do was to place those two in div within the container, and place div which is expanding below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.expand').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 85%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.card .container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #E91818;
}

div.container div {
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.title {}

.card h4 {
  display: inline;
}

.price {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="title">
  <h4 class="company">company name</h4>
  <span class="price">price</span>
    </span>
    <div class="expand">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```